How to Reduce BigQuery Costs with GA4 Streaming?
I’m analyzing our GA4 data in BigQuery to understand daily user behavior. However, I’ve noticed that the costs are much higher when using BigQuery’s streaming option in GA4 (as opposed to a daily batch load), likely due to the additional streaming charges.
Our service generates around 50 million user events daily, which exceeds the daily batch load limit, so we had to use the streaming option. Our current cost breakdown for BigQuery is roughly streaming: loading: analyzing = 20: 10: 1.
Are there any best practices, or alternative methods, to reduce the cost of streaming and loading data into BigQuery? I couldn’t find specific documentation, so any advice would be appreciated!
Thank you!
ps. GPT translated.
